# When designing a UI interface for MDPI and HDPI ANdroid how do i beat the height issue?

Tags: android, size, height, hdpi, mdpi

Having designed an interface for HDPI in Fireworks (480x800) and now moving it over ready for an MDPI version (320x480) i've come across an issue

Proportionally, the HDPI screen is slightly taller than the MDPI screen.

I know my images will resize, but even still am losing some space height wise

Evyerthing fits on screen beautifully on HDPI version....but now its resized down to MDPI the smaller proportion in height means i'm more stuck for space.

How does one avoid this issue?

I asked the developer if the space between elements can be altered for the MDPI version (eg, on a screen with 8 text fields.... the space between the fields is shortened), he said it will work on percentage of the screen etc.....that's all ok...problem is that

A 480x800 screen -- if this is downsized (proportionally width and height) to a width of 320, the height ends up as  533, not 480.

Therefore i lose 53 pixels in height.

Have I got confused? How do i sort this out?
Much thanks

Comment: That's a good question. I try keeping everything relative and defined in dpi. It can be a good start getting something to work even if it doesn't look optimal. After that, you can provide different layouts and resources.

Answer (score 2):

First of all

> Proportionally, the HDPI screen is slightly taller than the MDPI screen.

You can't say taller it or not. Density **doesn't** define resolution.

> Evyerthing fits on screen beautifully on HDPI version....but now its resized down to MDPI the smaller proportion in height means i'm more stuck for space.

So, as I said - MDPI also doesn't means that your screen resolution is less than HDPI screen resolution. For example, I have an tablet with 1280x800 resolution and MDPI screen. Get it?

Looks like it's better for you to provide different layouts for different **sizes** of devices (small, medium, large, xlarge).

Comment: Thanks... that's what I'm about to do. From what I understand...if I make my baseline design at 320x533. Then when exporting images...for HDPI i multiply by 1.5 for the size of export, and for MDPI i multiply by 0.75  - then it should come out ok.... Correct me if im wrong.

That would mean in my baseline image if I had a 100x100button....when exporting to mdpi it would become 75x75px and when exporting to hdpi it would become 150x150px  --- does that sound ok?  Then i am using the proportion of 3:4:6 as advised by android..... Then i avoid my spacing issues as i get the height i wanted back.

Comment: @user1517322 you're almost right, but 0.75 is for ldpi, and mdpi is your baseline.

Answer (score 0):

its better use layout weight and also make sure you use desipixel dp instead of px everywhere while designing your ui in xml. The best way to practice while designing ui is to ensure that the application will work and look fine regard less of the screen size

For more information on layout weight check this [link](http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/312)

Answer (score -1):

Use a [ScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html). However, I wouldn't recommend designing a layout for a fixed screen size, or even for a fixed ratio.

Comment: Trying to avoid scrollview as much as possible for this screen in the app. But thanks anyway